# Beginning Programming: How do I pass an ArrayAdapter to RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand what other alternative I have if I can't write this code:

```
  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,bluetoothDevices);

  recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I have started to learn Java and I am taking a freshman class that requires us to write a mobile app, but there is no instruction on how to do this. This class is not a programming class, it's a project based course so everyone has to learn everything on their own. I have literally been introduced to android a week ago.

My other question is how does android store text files?

Comment: You can't use ArrayAdapter with recycler view, you need to make a separate class and extend it via RecyclerView.Adapter, for more detail you google the tutorial for that.

Comment: Check these:
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example
https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview

Comment: I've looked at that and it looks like it involves way too much revision. I have to jump around all of those pages to modify both the XML markups and the mainactivity. Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: "My other question is how does android store text files?" You should try to keep your post focused on one question/issue. If you have another question, you should create a separate post for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter isn't meant to be used with RecyclerView. If you want to keep your ArrayAdapter, you can change your RecyclerView to a ListView:

```
// Change to a ListView
// (Remember to change it in your layout as well)
ListView myListView = findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringItems);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will work fine for simple data but, if you need to display more complex data or if you require more customization or performance, using RecyclerView is the recommended approach.